# No visible @interface for 'BlahDataController' declares the selector 'aMethod:

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Very strange, i am trying to call a method from the class which is failing with following error:

/Users/sun/Desktop/iphone/ViewController.m:64:19: No visible @interface for 'SocketIOSignaling' declares the selector 'RoomNow'

But when i am calling from the same class same type of other method just with different name that works.

Can anyone please advise?

1) SocketIOSignaling.h:

```
...
- (void)SameRoomNow; // <<< this works
- (void)RoomNow; //<<< this is not working???
...
```

2) SocketIOSignaling.m:

```
...
- (void)SameRoomNow { // << this is working
  ...
}

- (void)RoomNow { // << this is not working???
  ...
}
...
```

**3) ViewController.m:  (Problem is here while calling RoomNow)**

```
#import "SocketIOSignaling.h"

@property (strong, nonatomic) SocketIOSignaling* yumyumyum;

- (void)buttonPressed:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
  NSLog(@"OK OK OK Tapped"); 

  self.yumyumyum = [[SocketIOSignaling alloc] initWith:YES];

  [self.yumyumyum SameRoomNow];   // This is WORKING
  [self.yumyumyum RoomNow];   // But - This is NOT NOT NOT working
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the usual - clean, clean build folder, clean derived data, rebuild?

Comment: @YumYumYum can you share the entire `SocketIOSignaling.h` file?

Comment: @YumYumYum There is no method in the `SocketIOSignaling` that is just `initWith:` which you are using in `buttonPressed:` method the actual method is `initWithVideo:` try cleaning that up and see if the problem goes away

Comment: Always start method names with a lowercase letter.  Not the problem, but following the standard patterns of the language will lead to a better code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode was building from long directory. After fixing the following header path, it was using the correct version of modified header file.

[image]